# Logitech keyboard K270, Mouse working but keyboard isn’t

Tags: keyboard

My mother brought me this wireless keyboard yesterday. The mouse works fine but I have no clue how to connect the keyboard to my windows 10. I have tried looking up tutorials but none works.

Comment: How is your Mouse hooked up (Bluetooth or little wireless bug plugged into a USB port)?  Did the pair (Keyboard/Mouse) comes as a pair or separate?  If a pair, is there a USB bug to plug into USB to make the Keyboard work?

Comment: Did you install the Logitech Unifying software yet?

Answer (score 2):

If the keyboard and mouse are seperate then follow these steps:
1) change the port the USB is plugged into.

If the keyboard and mouse came together or that previous step didn’t work, try these steps:
 2) check the batteries in the keyboard.

3) if that doesn’t work, it may be a driver issue.. You can fix this by reinstalling the driver. Click the "Start" button and then click "Control Panel" followed by "Device Manager." Double-click the keyboard device and then click the "Driver" tab. Click "Update Driver" to update your keyboard's driver. Windows will search for and install the best version of your driver. If none are found then you can go to Logitech Support to download and install the driver for your specific wireless keyboard. Reboot the computer after installing and your wireless keyboard should be reset and fully working again.

Comment: Changing ports worked for me. The keyboard and mouse weren't showing in setpoint in the laptop port but when I plugged it into the docking station they showed up straight away

Answer (score 0):

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WBi-nHVzns) on YouTube, and all I had to do was to add a USB extender cable into the computer, plug a unifying receiver dongle into the USB extender cable, and set the dongle in front of the monitor, and my problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a K270 keyboard with a Unifying receiver it will not work because it is NOT compatible with the Unifying system. Check it out, you will not find the Unifying logo on the K270. These are being sold on Amazon as Unifying and it is a scam that Amazon is doing NOTHING about!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for bashing Amazon, but Logitech is to blame for this.

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360023462213-K270-Technical-Specifications

At the above link you'll see that Logitech clearly states this hardware is meant to be used with Unifying software.  It even ships in a combo with a mouse and a unifying receiver.  I'll edit this answer if I find a resolution, but it looks like Logitech simply doesn't want people using this kb anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the unifying receiver that came with the original box containing the keyboard and mouse for MK270.  The old receiver will not work.  The unifying receiver was stuck in a slot in the end of my original cardboard box.  Then, the new keyboard and new mouse connected easily.